# CRM2011 - Why are existing values being deleted when I add a new option set value using InsertOptionValueRequest

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to add new values to a MS Dynamics CRM option set in C# with InsertOptionValueRequest, and when I do, some of the existing option set values get deleted.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
    ovRequest = new InsertOptionValueRequest
    {
        AttributeLogicalName = strOptionsetName,
        EntityLogicalName = strEntityName,
        Label = new Label(strLabel, LanguageCode)
    };
    _service.Execute(ovRequest);
```

I then publish entity with:

```
    pxReq1 = new PublishXmlRequest { ParameterXml = String.Format("<importexportxml><entities><entity>{0}</entity></entities></importexportxml>", strEntityName) };
    ospService.Execute(pxReq1);
```

I am finding this is happening both with Local Option Sets and Global Option Sets and can't see any pattern in the value being deleted. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in the SDK?

PS, can someone add a insertoptionvaluerequest tag to this, because I think that tag would be most relevant to this post.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer to my question. MS Dynamics is not deleting existing values, it is overwriting the label on existing option set values. This is definitely a bug as the command being run is InsertOptionValueRequest and there is a separate UpdateOptionValueReqequest for updating values.

To work around it, manually set the Value when inserting the record instead of relying on the system to generate one for you:

```
ovRequest = new InsertOptionValueRequest
{
    AttributeLogicalName = strOptionsetName,
    EntityLogicalName = strEntityName,
    Label = new Label(strLabel, LanguageCode),
    Value = MyNewValue
};
_service.Execute(ovRequest);
```